# Need to add not concatenate with USD

Tags: jquery, concatenation, addition

I know this question has been asked but each scenario is varied just enough to confuse me.

When a user changes the select then: #cost + #donation = #total

When a user types in #donation then: #cost + #donation = #total

I have it working but the total concatenates to "$30.00$20.00" instead of adding the 2 to "$50.00"

I believe parseFloat() has a lot to do with it.

Thank you!

```
<select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="type" name="type" required>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" disabled>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="donation" name="donation">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="total" disabled>
```

This is what I have pieced together:

```
    $("#type").change(function(){
    // this changes the input id=cost to match the select field id=type
    var typevalue = $( "#type" ).val();
    $('input[name=cost]').val(typevalue);


});

 $('#donation').keyup(function() {

   $(this).val(function(i,v) {
     return '$' + v.replace('$',''); //remove exisiting, add back.
   });

 });

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#type').change(calculate);
    $('#donation').keyup(calculate);

});

function calculate(e)
{
    $('#total').val($('#cost').val() + $('#donation').val());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert values to integer or float to make sure you are working with numbers:

```
function calculate(e)
{
    var cost = parseInt($('#cost').val().replace('$',''));
    var donation = parseInt($('#donation').val().replace('$',''));
    var total = cost + donation;
    $('#total').val('$'+ total );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the dollar sign from the number before adding: `String.replace("$","")`, then parse it using `parseFloat(value)`

Comment: removing the dollar sign gives me "30.0020.00"

Comment: then you need to parse it first using `parseFloat(var)` :)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your input field in a `<label>` and add the $ sign there.

I would also use `<input type='number'>` to make things easier for your customers.

Also change the selector for cost to `$('#cost')`